# Doctrine 2 Model entity to associative array

Tags: doctrine-orm

I cannot figure out how a function is called that would do the following:

```
class Page {

  private $id;
  private $title;
  private $content;

  .. setters / getters

}


// Normal page object
$page = $em->find('Page', 1);

// What I need
$page_as_array = array(
  'id' => $page->getId(),
  'title' => $page->getTitle(),
  'content' => $page->getContent()
);

// What I would like to type
$page_as_array = $page->asArray()
```

Is this possible? (I know I could probably create my own asArray() for each model, but why reinvent the wheel)